# WAMP installation error: MySQL port

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium (yuck).  I have MySQL already installed.  The port I am using for various MySQL projects is 3306.  I have used MySQL Workbench to create a database for a planned Drupal site.  When I login as administrator and try to install WAMP, the installation program asks me to specify the port for MySQL.  I enter 3306 and receive the error: "It seems you do not have enough permissions to bind to the port or the port is already taken by another application. Please select another one."  When I try a different port and complete the installation, there are no servers listed for me to start.  Is it possible to convince WAMP to allow me to use 3306, which is my preference?  Thanks.

Comment: Check what processes are running and end them if possible, maybe one of them is using that port and then try again??

Comment: I believe you need to run the program as an administrator to bind to 3306. (Right click on program > run as administrator)

Comment: I login as administrator and run as admin, but still encounter the error.  I stop my MySQL service and then try to install.  The install routine doesn't ask for a MySQL port but gives me this error (repeated 3 times): Can't connect to MySQL on localhost (10013). This error is repeated in another error dialog. Last error: Unable to instal MySQL as a service with the name wampstackMySQL. The installation actually finishes. I run the utility and try to start servers.  Nothing happens, even 15 minutes later.  Question: Has anyone installed WAMP on Win7 Home Premium?  It seems impossible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Switch of all other running programs, for example - skype. And restart your wamp server

Comment: I've restarted the PC, immediately logged in as administrator, run the install program as administrator. Nothing has changed.  It won't let me use 3306.  If I stop the MySQL service and run the install I still get the errors described above (i.e., 10013).  In addition, I can no longer use MySQL Workbench to connect to my MySQL databases.  Also, I can no longer start MySQL from the command line. I'm on the verge of giving up.  I've had success with LAMP.  It just doesn't seem possible to install WAMP on Win 7 Home Premium (when MySQL is already there). I have to now repair my beloved Workbench.